# What does [super viewWillAppear] do, and when is it required?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//something here
[super viewWillAppear];
}
```

Is `[super viewWillAppear];` always required? If not when and why do you use it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First of all, the correct boiler plate should be:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   //something here
}
```

In other words, call `super` *first*, then do your own thing. And you have to pass the `animated` parameter to `super`.

You usually want to call the super class' implementation first in any method. In many languages it's required. In Objective-C it's not, but you can easily run into trouble if you don't put it at the top of your method. (That said, I sometimes break this pattern.)

Is calling `super's` implementation **required**? In the case of this particular method you could get unexpected behavior if you don't call it (especially if you have subclassed a `UINavigationController` for example). So the answer is **no** not in a technical sense, but you should probably always do it.

However, in many other methods there may be good reasons for not calling `super`.

Comment: interesting. a lot of code samples i've seen call super last. i wonder why.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's not that uncommon. Would be interesting to hear someone else's insights on this. In this case, it makes absolutely no practical difference, but for example in "loadView" you really should call super first, and on the whole I think it's a very good habit.

Comment: I agree that's why it can be quite confusing. SO community please share your thoughts.

Comment: I was under the impression that it is sort of dependent on what you are trying to do. I try and call it after to be safe unless I'm modifying things which will be overwritten by super. There's a similar discussion on an android dev thread which talks about this: http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/2010-07/msg00394.html

Comment: Here's a counter example: when overriding dealloc, you MUST call super after doing all your own deallocation, otherwise you're almost sure to get a crash. So I guess the truth is that the correct calling order depends on context, which is not ideal.

Comment: Yes, Felixyz, but it's a simple rule: Let the super build first, let the super tear down last.

Comment: I should I also mention: I spent most of today tracking down a crash on armv6 devices that was fixed by calling `[super viewWillAppear]` in the right order. I have never seen matter before, but if it matters once there are probably other places where it matters too.

Comment: @Steven: Yikes. Do you know exactly what cause the crash?

Comment: I'm seeing the problem here. People don't know why exactly they are calling the super's viewwillappear, they just think since the books says to do so, we should.   First you have to know who is your super, and what it's implementation of viewwillappear does before you go calling it.

Answer (score 9):

Calling `super` method provide possibility to execute code in parent class.

Regarding your question according to [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:)

[image]

So, yes, this method required.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, calling `[super viewWillAppear]` in the first line, when calling `reloadData` after that, makes it impossible to retrieve the previously selected row when coming back from a detail view. When `[super viewWillAppear]` is the last sentence, you can get the selected row and show the previously selected row hint. This happens only when using `[tableView reloadData]` inside `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Yes because your super's viewwillappear(in which you are the implementor) is probably doing some UI initializations.

Comment: This fixed iOS9 specific issue - 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'.

Comment: Selected rows are cleared during reload data, you need to capture the selected rows before and then set them again after reload. UITableViewController viewWillAppear only calls reload if tableView.numberOfSections is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have 2 class, a Parent and a Child. Child inherits from Parent. They have a method called greet which returns a string.

Here is what the parent method looks like:

Code:

```
-(NSString *)greet {
   return @"Hello";
}
```

We want the child to learn from his parents. So we use super to say greet how Mommy would greet, but with our own little additions too.

Code:
// Inherits from Parent

```
-(NSString *)greet {
  NSString *parentGreeting = [super greet];
  return [parentGreeting stringByAppendingString:@", Mommy"]
}
```

So now Parent greets "Hello", and the Child greets "Hello, Mommy". Later on, if we change the parent's greet to return just "Hi", then both classes will be affected and you will have "Hi" and "Hi, Mommy".

super is used to call a method as defined by a superclass. It is used to access methods that have been overriden by subclasses so that the class can wrap its own code around a method that it's parent class implements. It's very handy if you are doing any sort of inheritance at all.