# How to handle return event in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have simple question.
I using storyboard with Navigation Controller.
Application performs a push segue from first VC to another. 
After user press a "Back" button, he will return, to first VC.
I need to handle this event, to refresh display data.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can override `viewDidAppear:` of the first vc and refresh from there if the data is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you need to refresh the data in first VC. Implement **viewDidAppear:** in first VC

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  // refresh data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this question: [back button callback in navigationController in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217992/back-button-callback-in-navigationcontroller-in-ios)

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
   // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
   // in the navigation stack.  
}
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pre iOs 5.0 you can use -viewWillDisappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject:self]) {
        //...
    }
}
```

in iOS 5.0+ you can use -didMoveToParentViewController:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent{
    if(!parent){
        //...
    }
}
```