# UIKit - action when navigation controller did navigate back

Tags: ios, uikit

This should be absolutely trivial but I can't find anything so:

I have a simple storyboard with navigation controller where I push a view controller, let's call it "Jane", from a view controller called "Bob".

So Bob wants to do something whenever Jane is dismissed after tapping the "back" button, like so:

```
- (IBAction) janeWasDismissed:(UIViewController *)jane
{
   // bob wants to ask what Jane did.
}
```

It's the simplest thing right? But I can't figure it out, surely Unwind Segues are not the right way?
There must be a simple click & drag operation for this in Interface Builder, or a method on UIViewController which is called when the pushed view controller has popped?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not at all trivial. If Bob is going to need information from Jane, you need to *arrange* for Jane to send that information back to Bob. For example, in Jane's `viewWillDisappear:`, she can get herself a reference to Bob (by way of the navigation controller that they both share) and call some method in Bob.

You might object (quite reasonably) that this implies a knowledge of Bob's class on the part of Jane. The usual solution to *that* is even more non-trivial: it is that Bob, as he summons Jane, makes himself available to Jane as a delegate cast as a protocol that Jane defines. Thus Jane needs to know only one method of Bob - not his actual class, but the method that she herself has specified in her protocol.

Comment: hm, interesting! I'm kind of thinking it should really be the other way around: As Bob invokes Jane, Bob knows Jane already. Why should Jane have a reference to Bob?

Comment: The usual architecture is that Bob, as he summons Jane, makes himself available to Jane as a delegate cast as a protocol that Jane defines. Thus Jane needs to know only one method of Bob - not his actual class, but the method that she herself has specified in her protocol.

Comment: ok thanks - will do that if it's the thing one does. Still seems odd, as modal controllers (alert controller etc.) do it the other way around. On the other hand, I see how this model makes sense if the pushed VC needs to pull data from the parent VC.

Comment: No, modal controllers (presented view controllers) work the same way. This is the standard architecture for A creates B, B must hand info back to A as it goes out of existence. Even with a modern alert controller you are still handing B (the alert) a closure that refers back to A, and B must call it.

Comment: hm true, it just looks different when handling it a closure block. Ok I'm still confused actually. If I want to send a message to Bob in `viewWillDisappear:`, I still need to handle a case where Jane will disappear other than navigating back to Bob... finicky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217992/back-button-callback-in-navigationcontroller-in-ios

Comment: Jane's `viewWillDisappear` calls `isBeingDismissed` or `isMovingFromParentViewController` to find out what's happening.

Comment: Please see my book, and esp. my example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p264presentedViewController/ch19p601presentedViewController That's a presented view controller but the principle for pushed view controller is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple click & drag operation for this in Interface Builder.

There is no method on UIViewController which gets called when the pushed view controller has popped.

JaneViewController has to signal BobViewController.

```
class BobViewcontroller {
    var janeWasDismissed = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if janesWasDismissed {
            // Do something
            janeWasDismissed = false
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "go-to-jane" {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! JaneViewController
            destinationController.delegate = self
            self.janeWasDismissed = false
        }
    }
}

class JaneViewController {
    var delegate: BobViewcontroller?

    func dismissJane() {
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.janeWasDismissed = true
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
    }
}
```