# Need to Reload view after updating the details Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a small issue in Updating the details in the view. How to reload a view after successful updation to change the details.

Below is my code. Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in Advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]          delegate];
    profilearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First Name:",@"Last Name:",@"Date of Birth:",@"Email:",@"Gender:",@"Address:",@"Country:",@"State:",@"City:",@"ZipCode:",@"Phone:",@"Guardian / Caretaker Details:",@"Name:",@"Relationship:",@"Email:",@"Doctor Details:",@"Name:",@"Phone:",@"Email:",@"Insurance Details:",@"Name:",@"Email:",nil];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

   return 1;

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [profilearray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [profilearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FirstName"];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"LastName"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DOB"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Email"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==4)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Gender"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==5)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Address"];
    }  
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: After tableview cell you want to reload your view Please confirm

Comment: Yes, in my Edit Profile when update button is clicked and redirected to UIVIew, there the view should be Reloaded and details should be updated

Answer (score 0):

use [tableView reloadData] for updating tableview

Answer (score 0):

Simple Use this Do not need to view refresh or reload

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [tableView reloadData] 
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your data source array `profilearray` keeps getting re-assigned the same value every time the view appears. Maybe initialise it once in `viewDidLoad`.
- After the array is updated, use `[tableView reloadData]` to reload the table view.
- Do not call `viewDidLoad` on your own, and get rid of `setNeedsDisplay` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        profilearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First Name:",@"Last Name:",@"Date of Birth:",@"Email:",@"Gender:",@"Address:",@"Country:",@"State:",@"City:",@"ZipCode:",@"Phone:",@"Guardian / Caretaker Details:",@"Name:",@"Relationship:",@"Email:",@"Doctor Details:",@"Name:",@"Phone:",@"Email:",@"Insurance Details:",@"Name:",@"Email:",nil];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- profilearray:- Perhaps this is your array from where you are getting data in tableview and also storing data in it
- viewWillAppear :- this method is called when view is appear
- [tableView_Outlet reloadData] :- this method reload your tableview with new data

So in this scenario never call viewWillAper Because this is not standard way to do 
Find point where your data is updated then call "reloadData" 
 [For more about viewWillApear hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348204/what-does-super-viewwillappear-do-and-when-is-it-required)
Thanks